# Understanding Moments function in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

When finding the center coordinates using moments in OpenCV,the point is found using

```
Point(moment[i].m10/moment[i].m00,moment[i].m01/moment[i].m00);
```

Can somebody please explain this bit to me?What do "m10","m00","m01" and "m00" mean??

Comment: How is moment defined?

Comment: are you asking for this: Moments moments(InputArray array, bool binaryImage=false ) ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Definition of moments in image processing is borrowed from physics. Assume that each pixel in image has weight that is equal to its intensity. Then the point you defined is centroid (a.k.a. center of mass) of image.

Assume that I(x,y) is the intensity of pixel (x,y) in image. Then m(i,j) is the sum for all possible x and y of: I(x,y) * (x^i) * (y^j).

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) you can read the documentation of moments used in OpenCV. They are called raw moments.

And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) you can read a wiki article about all kinds of image moments (raw moments, central moments, scale/rotation invariant moments and so on). It is pretty good one and I recommend reading it.

Comment: thanks @Michael but I am still confused with this. By m(i,j) you mean the above m10,m00 etc. But why does it have to divide by m00?and why this I(x,y) * (x^i) * (y^j)?

Comment: Center of mass is a weighed average of pixels (where each weight is the intensity). Weighted average of something is: sum of weight(i)*item(i) divided by sum of weight(i). In case of an image sum of weights is equal sum of gray levels is equal to m00.

Comment: You wrote, " Assume that each pixel in image has weight that is equal to its **intensity**". From the Wikipedia link, " an image moment is a certain particular weighted average (moment) of the image pixels' **intensities**". Does intensity here mean the `color intensity` (which is same as 'color saturation')? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Solace, I was talking about monochrome image, not a color image. Each pixel has only one value - its intensity (weight). Function Moments() expects a single channel image. If you are working with color image, you can convert it into single channel image in many different ways.

Comment: How can i get the area of a contour after having all m00, m01. etc?

Comment: m00 is the area if you calculate moments of contour (m00 is a sum of gray levels if you calculate moments of an image)